# Assigned Resource and Service Appointment in Field Service Lightning

Tags: admin, fsl

I am trying to get text messages from Appointment Assistance. I have a query does status in Service Appointment when changed to 'EnRoute' or 'Last Mile' Will it will automatically changes the LocationStatus in Assigned Resource too?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.